# Convert shapely polygon coordinates

Tags: python, shapefile, geojson, shapely, fiona

I am trying to work with a shapefile using shapely, fiona and python. The original coordinate system is in latitude and longitude that I am trying to convert to state plane system. So I want an updated shapefile with coordinates as statePlane. I converted the json object:

```
fc = fiona.open("sample.shp")   
geoJsonObj = shapefile_record['geometry']
array_coordinates = np.array(geoJsonObj['coordinates'])
array_newCoordinates = copy.deepcopy(array_coordinates)
for counter in range(0,len(array_coordinates[0])):
    long,lat = p1(array_coordinates[0][counter][0],array_coordinates[0][counter][1])
    #where p1 is a function to do the conversion
    array_newCoordinates[0][counter][0] = long
    array_newCoordinates[0][counter][1] = lat

geoJsonObj['coordinates'] = array_newCoordinates.tolist()
```

when i check the coordinates, i get state plane coordinates according to the transformation.

n. However, when i open the individual shapes/polygons within the shapefile, the coordinates are still latitude and longitude. why does this happen?

----EDIT 1-----

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import fiona
from fiona.crs import from_epsg

dest_crs = from_epsg(4269)
shape = fiona.open("Sample.shp")
original = Proj(shape.crs) # EPSG:4326 in your case
destination = Proj('+proj=lcc +lat_1=36.41666666666666 +lat_2=35.25      +lat_0=34.33333333333334 +lon_0=-86 +x_0=600000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83  +no_defs')
with fiona.open('new.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile',shape.schema.copy(),crs = dest_crs) as output:
    for feat in shape:       
        print feat['geometry']['coordinates']
        for counter in range(0,len(feat['geometry']['coordinates'][0])):
            long,lat =  feat['geometry']['coordinates'][0][counter]
            x,y = transform(original, destination,long,lat)
            feat['geometry']['coordinates'][0][counter] = (x,y)
        output.write(feat)
```

Comment: Although I made an answer, I don't see the point to use Python here. Why don't you use ogr2ogr? Do you know the EPSG, ESRI code for your expected state plane coordinates ?

Comment: I didnt know about that. I am very new to this field and therefore, didnt know.

Comment: I had skipped defining the destination crs while opening the new shp file. When i updated the code, the program crashes as soon as i try to open the new.shp file.

Comment: If your file is Sample.shp, the Sample.prj file content (open it with a text editor) associated will help us deduce the exact projection. Can you add it content in your post?

Comment: The content is : GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

Comment: For your new --EDIT1--, look below

Answer (score 15):

To change projections with Fiona, use the [pyproj](https://code.google.com/p/pyproj/) module.

Example with a point shapefile (you can simplify the algorithm):

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import fiona
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
shape = fiona.open('sample.shp')
original = Proj(shape.crs) # EPSG:4326 in your case
destination = Proj(init='EPSG:...') # your new EPSG
with fiona.open('new.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', shape.schema.copy(), crs=from_epsg(...)) as output:
    for feat in shape:
        long,lat =  feat['geometry']['coordinates']
        x,y = transform(original, destination,long,lat)
        # change only the coordinates of the feature
        feat['geometry']['coordinates'] = (x,y)
        output.write(feat)
```

If you want to work with the GeoJSON format:

```
with fiona.open('sample.shp') as source:
    records = list(source)
geojson = {"type": "FeatureCollection","features": records}
```

And use the same method with the GeoJSON format (with [pyproj](https://code.google.com/p/pyproj/))

For a polygon, do the same thing with the points of the polygon

```
for feat in shape:
   for point in feat['geometry']['coordinates'][0]: # = LinearRing of the polygon
       x,y = pt
       ....
```

#### new

In your script, why `counter`?
- `feat['geometry']['coordinates']` is a nested list (Polygon)
- `feat['geometry']['coordinates'][0]` also (LinearRing of the Polygon)
- `feat['geometry']['coordinates'][0][x]` is a Point of the LinearRing

So:

```
with fiona.open('new.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', shape.schema.copy(), crs=from_epsg(...)) as output:
    for feat in shape: # feat = one polygon of the shapefile
        out_linearRing = [] # empty list for the LinearRing of transformed coordinates
        for point in feat['geometry']['coordinates'][0]: # LinearRing of the Polygon
            long,lat =  point  # one point of the LinearRing
            x,y = transform(original, destination,long,lat) # transform the point
            out_linearRing.append((x,y)) # add all the points to the new LinearRing
        # transform the resulting LinearRing to  a Polygon and write it
        feat['geometry']['coordinates'] = [out_linearRing]
        output.write(feat)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using pyproj. The p in my case was the destination projection (should have mentioned that). Here is what i am using based on your suggestion. But as soon as I execute the statement output.write(feat), the program crashes. please See Edit 1 for updated code

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But some of the problems still persist. If I include crs=from_epsg(4269) while opening the the new.shp, the program crashes. If I omit it, the program crashes while executing output.write(feat)

Comment: Here are the details:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 53b1ecd8
  Fault Module Name: ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18247
  Fault Module Timestamp: 521ea8e7
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00022289
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.2
  Locale ID: 16393
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: Can you add a `print feat` right before `output.write(feat)` and write back here with the value of the last feature that is printed?

Answer (score 3):

Didn't try but the most obvious is where do you save your new file? Or why if you want to do 'in-place' change, you only open the shp file without changing the mode to be able to write it.

Also more in general, use the `with` statement like in [official docs](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) because for example in your code, you do not close the file whereas with `with` it's automatic.

Comment: I will use the with statement. Thank you. How do I save the file? More importantly, does changing the geojsonObj's coordinates in my case ensure that all the polygon's will have their coordinates transformed as well?

Comment: Read the docs, please, writing is already documented http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html#writing-vector-data

Comment: In practice, you don't need `with`to close a shapefile with Fiona. It is recommended but not necessary.

Comment: You're right, IMO, just more Pythonic and a good way to not forget closing file