# How to Identify Coordinate System (CRS) from projection file using Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapefile

I am working on many shapefiles (their corresponding projection files are also presented).

Every shapefile has a different Coordinate System, so it becomes difficult to plot these in a generic manner.

How can I identify with Python what is the CRS used in the shapefile?

For example, the `".prj"` file for some shapefiles is given below, but I am not able to identify what is the CRS to be used.

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

GEOGCS["WGS84(DD)", DATUM["WGS84", SPHEROID["WGS84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH]]

GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

GEOGCS["WGS84(DD)", DATUM["WGS84", SPHEROID["WGS84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH]]
```

Comment: Which python library or tools do you use to read your shapefile?

Comment: I have tried GeoPandas, Shapely, and Fionna

Answer (score 6):

For example with fiona:

```
c = fiona.open('docs/data/test_uk.shp')
crs = c.crs
```

find it in the [docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/fiona/latest/fiona.pdf) page 28

If you need the EPSG code there is good inspiration to take [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121441/convert-shapely-polygon-coordinates) using pyproj

Answer (score 2):

A number of Python modules exist to work with CRS or projection files

- [Pypi:ESPSG](https://pypi.org/search/?q=epsg&o=-created) or [Pypi:CRS](https://pypi.org/search/?q=crs&o=)
- [GitHub: EPSG](https://github.com/search?l=Python&o=desc&q=epsg&s=updated&type=Repositories)

For example, you can use [epsg-ident](https://pypi.org/project/epsg-ident/) or [sridentify](https://github.com/cmollet/sridentify) (Quickly get the EPSG code from a .prj file or WKT)

```
from sridentify import Sridentify
ident = Sridentify()
# from file
ident.from_file('schisto.prj')
ident.get_epsg()
31370
# from WKT
ident = Sridentify(prj="""GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]])
ident.get_epsg()
4326
```

But it doesn't always work

```
ident =  Sridentify(prj = """GEOGCS["WGS84(DD)", DATUM["WGS84", SPHEROID["WGS84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH]""")
ident.get_epsg()
# nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it not just that simple as below (I know he wanted to know from prj file but I think this is more simple)?

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"PATH TO FOLDER OR GDB"

featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in featureclasses:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    spatialRef = desc.spatialReference
    print(spatialRef.Name)
```

https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/115

Comment: Thanks for this,  but is there any alternate solution which does not use arcpy.

Answer (score 0):

In two lines using geopandas (`pip install geopandas`):

```
import geopandas as gpd
print(gpd.read_file('world-administrative-boundaries.shp').crs)
```